# using keyword inside foreach ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Inside my view I need to use a form on every iteration, but if I put `@using` inside `foreach` it isn't working,

```
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayName(item.name)</td>

        @using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>

        <td>@Html.DropDownList("idid", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["list"], "Select ...", new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.id, new { Value = item.id })</td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" /></td>


        }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: What is `list` in `@foreach (var item in list)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's List<Product>

Comment: Show the full code. You have multiple problems with the code you have shown. You creating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes).  `@Html.TextBoxFor(quantity => quantity.quantity, ..)` makes no sense? Neither does `new { Value = item.id }` in `@Html.DisplayFor()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is not well formed, and I suspect that is the reason you are getting the error. When your form element is created, it will contain `<td>` elements, not a complete table. When it is generated, it will look like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <form>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You must put the form inside of the `<td>` elements or outside of the `<table>` element for it to produce valid HTML.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Or

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form><!-- input and other html elements here --></form></td>
        <td><form><!-- input and other html elements here --></form></td>
        <td><form><!-- input and other html elements here --></form></td>
        <td><form><!-- input and other html elements here --></form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How can i end that form? @Html.endform() says this "Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'object'"

Comment: You don't need to call `@Html.EndForm()` because you are using curly brackets, which will do that automatically.

Comment: problem resolved it was bad html structure from was ending outside </tr> closing tag , thanks